# Acess single values from Abaqus FieldValueArray with Python

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm currently writing an post processing script for a detailed analysis of Abaqus simulations. My current problem is that I would like to Access some Abaqus Field Object data and Change values, which are below a Limit value. E.g. if  the values is lower than 0 --> Change value to 0. I'm planning to do this Task with a simple if Statement. However I have some Problems to Access the data correctly. I am using Python.

My Code Looks like this:

```
strain_n = session.odbs[odbName].steps['Load'].frames[n].fieldOutputs['SDV2']
#SDV2 is a Scalar field, strain in y-direction from Abaqus UMAT
```

As far as I understood the abqus documentation correctly, I can access the FieldData with using:

```
data = strain_n.values
```

Unfortunately I do not understand how I should proceed I tried some combination with data but Nothing really did work. I am not able to access the data at one Integration Point nor am I able to Change the value.
The command len(data) tells me 2304 which corresponds well with my expectations hence I’m using 576 Elements with 4 integrations Points = 2304.

Can someone please help me ? Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: print data, you should see the values. You cannot change them. Changing odb is not allowed. You could, however, create a new fieldoutput with adjusted values and write it to the odb.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to print out the data:

```
for v in data:
    print '%d %6.4f' % (v.elementLabel, v.data)
```

OR you can write data into file:

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for v in data:
        f.write('%d %6.4f' % (v.elementLabel, v.data) + '\n')
```